# SpriteKit: Objects go underneath each other

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have two tanks in my game, one red and one blue.

I've set their PhysicsBody, but instead of hitting each other, they go underneath each other.

[Simulator Screenshot (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm8ur.png)

PhysicsCategory :

```
struct physicsCategory {
    static let Bullet : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    static let Enemy : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let MainTank : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let EnemyTank : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
}
```

Here's the blue tank code :

```
MainTank = (self.childNode(withName: "tank") as? SKSpriteNode)!
MainTank.name = "blueTank"

MainTank.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.MainTank
MainTank.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.Enemy
MainTank.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.Enemy
```

Red tank's:

```
enemyTank = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tank_red")
enemyTank.size = CGSize(width: 76, height: 92)
enemyTank.name = "enemyTank"
enemyTank.zPosition = 0
enemyTank.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: enemyTank.size)
enemyTank.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.EnemyTank
enemyTank.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.Enemy
enemyTank.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.MainTank

enemyTank.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you must have enemyTank's collisionBitMask set to the categorybitMask of the the MainTank

Comment: @Muffinman2497, can you correct me then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the line

```
enemyTank.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.Enemy
```

To

```
enemyTank.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.MainTank
```